# How to prevent Google forming url's from JavaScript in ascx control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-crawler

Here's the problem: On an .ascx control, there is a short Javascript block. The script, among other things, refers to a method in the control and generates DoP meta tags for different pages on a website.

Problem is, Google crawler reads the Javascript in the pages and thinks every DoP meta tag is an url of some kind. This is probably because there is a forward slash in the tag(?). In the end, Google has indexed massive amounts of non-existent urls on the website and given them 404 status. Is there a way around this? For example, is it possible to put nofollow tags directly to the Javascript?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!-- DoP tag -->
   var v = {};
   v["sample"] = '/Product_A_';
</script>
```

Google crawler seems to index an url "http://www.my web site.com/Product_A_" from above script.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples please. The js and the resulting meta tags. What does DoP mean?

Comment: DoP = Document Path.

--- product page ---
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!-- DoP tag -->
 var v = {};
 v["sample"] = '/Product_A_';
</script>
--- product page ---

Comment: Line changes messed up in last comment, but the '/Product_A_' tag results in Google indexing it as a url with websites base url in front of it.

Comment: Is there a good reason that you need to use this script? What does it do for you? The answer below provides you with a way to inform Googlebot about which things to index or not, but I think it's important to understand what you need the script for in the first place.

Comment: @LauriI would you be able to edit your original question with the code added, so it's easier to read than in the comments please?

Comment: Would breaking the expression up help? eg. `v["sample"] = '/' + 'Product_A_';`

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a site map and a robots.txt?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

That way, the search engines will only crawl and index the content specified in the sitemap and you can use the robots.txt to exclude the extranious content, especially if it all follows a specific pattern.

Or use th meta tag "nofollow" on these pages, meaning the search engines will not follow any additional links:

http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

Comment: We have site map and robot.txt in use, also these pages have content that should be indexed. Only the tags inside scripts should be excluded from indexing.

Comment: So why not use the robots.txt to exclude the tags in the scripts? Or on these pages the `NOFOLLOW` still indexes the page, it just doesn't follow any links - but the sitemap should take care of that?